# How to store 'multiple values' in 'multiple variables' automatically?

Tags: vba, vb6

I wanted to know whether the below can be submitted in any other way simply. I'm inserting the multiple values from a table "moncal" into the table "cumulative"(which calculates the average of the attendace of the student for all the subjects). Moncal table has totlec(total lecture) and totpre(total lecture the student present) values and from that, I am calculating the average of attendance of all the students. So, while  fetching the values from 'moncal' I will get multiple values for a particular "rollno" and which will be stored in a variable a1,a2..... and b1,b2.... So, is there any way of declaring variable simply and automatically from this.
This is the code I've used:

```
Dim avg As Double
Set p1 = New ADODB.Recordset
p1.Open "select distinct(rollno) from moncal order by rollno asc", conn()

For rollno = 1 To p1.RecordCount



 Set p2 = New ADODB.Recordset
 p2.Open "select totpre,subcode from moncal where rollno = " & p1.Fields(0) & " order by subcode asc ", conn()
  tot1 = 0
 tot2 = 0
 'avg = 0
 a1 = 0
 a2 = 0
 a3 = 0
 a4 = 0
 a5 = 0
 a6 = 0
 a7 = 0
 a8 = 0
 a9 = 0
 a10 = 0
 a11 = 0
 a12 = 0
 a13 = 0
 a14 = 0
 a15 = 0
 b1 = 0
 b2 = 0
 b3 = 0
 b4 = 0
 b5 = 0
 b6 = 0
 b7 = 0
 b8 = 0
 b9 = 0
 b10 = 0
 b11 = 0
 b12 = 0
 b13 = 0
 b14 = 0
 b15 = 0
 
 For x = 1 To p2.RecordCount


  
  If x = 1 Then
  a1 = p2.Fields(0)
  ElseIf x = 2 Then
  a2 = p2.Fields(0)
  ElseIf x = 3 Then
  a3 = p2.Fields(0)
  ElseIf x = 4 Then
  a4 = p2.Fields(0)
  ElseIf x = 5 Then
  a5 = p2.Fields(0)
  ElseIf x = 6 Then
  a6 = p2.Fields(0)
  ElseIf x = 7 Then
  a7 = p2.Fields(0)
    ElseIf x = 8 Then
  a8 = p2.Fields(0)
  ElseIf x = 9 Then
  a9 = p2.Fields(0)
    ElseIf x = 10 Then
  a10 = p2.Fields(0)
    ElseIf x = 11 Then
  a11 = p2.Fields(0)
    ElseIf x = 12 Then
  a12 = p2.Fields(0)
   ElseIf x = 13 Then
  a13 = p2.Fields(0)
   ElseIf x = 14 Then
  a14 = p2.Fields(0)
   ElseIf x = 15 Then
  a15 = p2.Fields(0)
   ElseIf x = 16 Then
  a16 = p2.Fields(0)
   ElseIf x = 17 Then
  a17 = p2.Fields(0)
   ElseIf x = 18 Then
  a18 = p2.Fields(0)
   ElseIf x = 19 Then
  a19 = p2.Fields(0)
   ElseIf x = 20 Then
  a20 = p2.Fields(0)
  Else
  Exit For
  p2.MoveNext
  Next
 



Set p3 = New ADODB.Recordset
p3.Open "select totlec,subcode from moncal where rollno = " & p1.Fields(0) & " order by subcode asc ", conn()
 
  For y = 1 To p3.RecordCount
 
   If y = 1 Then
  b1 = p3.Fields(0)
  ElseIf y = 2 Then
  b2 = p3.Fields(0)
  ElseIf y = 3 Then
  b3 = p3.Fields(0)
  ElseIf y = 4 Then
  b4 = p3.Fields(0)
    ElseIf y = 5 Then
  b5 = p3.Fields(0)
    ElseIf y = 6 Then
  b6 = p3.Fields(0)
  ElseIf y = 7 Then
  b7 = p3.Fields(0)
    ElseIf y = 8 Then
  b8 = p3.Fields(0)
    ElseIf y = 9 Then
  b9 = p3.Fields(0)
    ElseIf y = 10 Then
  b10 = p3.Fields(0)
    ElseIf y = 11 Then
  b11 = p3.Fields(0)
    ElseIf y = 12 Then
  b12 = p3.Fields(0)
      ElseIf y = 13 Then
  b13 = p3.Fields(0)
      ElseIf y = 14 Then
  b14 = p3.Fields(0)
      ElseIf y = 15 Then
  b15 = p3.Fields(0)
      ElseIf y = 16 Then
  b16 = p3.Fields(0)
      ElseIf y = 17 Then
  b17 = p3.Fields(0)
      ElseIf y = 18 Then
  b18 = p3.Fields(0)
      ElseIf y = 19 Then
  b19 = p3.Fields(0)
      ElseIf y = 20 Then
  b20 = p3.Fields(0)
  Else
  Exit For
  End If
  p3.MoveNext
  Next

  
 roll = p1.Fields(0)
 tot1 = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 + a12 + a13 + a14 + a15 + a16 + a17 + a18 + a19 + a20
 tot2 = b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6 + b7 + b8 + b9 + b10 + b11 + b12 + b13 + b14 + b15 + b16 + b17 + b18 + b19 + b20
 avg = tot1 / tot2 * 100
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not leverage the abilities of the database itself?  Instead of pulling back all this data and processing it with code, use SQL functions like SUM and AVG instead.  I'm assuming you are using SQL Server, but this should be doable across other DB's, too.

Comment: Is this a VBA project or VB6? They are similar but not identical, and rarely a question is truly about both. Thx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The question is for Visual Basic. And I'm using MS Access as my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all of those variables if the aim is only to sum the values...

```
Dim avg As Double

Set p1 = New ADODB.Recordset
p1.Open "select distinct(rollno) from moncal order by rollno asc", conn()

For rollno = 1 To p1.RecordCount
    
    roll = p1.Fields(0)
    Set p2 = New ADODB.Recordset
    p2.Open "select totpre,totlec,subcode from moncal where rollno = " & roll & " order by subcode asc ", conn()
    
    tot1 = 0
    tot2 = 0
    
    For x = 1 To p2.RecordCount
        tot1 = tot1 + p2.Fields(0).Value
        tot2 = tot2 + p2.Fields(1).Value
        If x = 20 Then Exit For
        p2.MoveNext
    Next

    avg = tot1 / tot2 * 100
    Debug.Print rollno, avg
    
Next rollno
```